# Redirecting to appsflyer OneLink?

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, appsflyer

I'm looking into AppFlyer's OneLink service for deep linking. I am trying to find out if I redirect from say companywebsite.com/stuff/1 to a universal link/app deep link on appflyer like appflyer.com/stuff/1 for example, would it successfully open both my iOS and Android App?

Past Research:
iOS Universal Link does not seem to work? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26760?q=universal%20deep%20linking

Blog post stating iOS redirection also does not work:
https://medium.com/bumble-tech/universal-links-for-android-and-ios-1ddb1e70cab0#4110

Android:
I couldn't find a good source for universal link/android app link redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iOS** - If the redirection is done in the context of the browser (Safari), the first click is passed to the redirection link, in this case (onelink.me) and Universal Links should work. Redirection from a different source/app can change the behaviour.

**Android** - The main issue with App Links is that it's blocked on most browsers and you are limited to Chrome only on most cases.